# Laravel collection group by like category name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

lets say I have a collection of objects fruits each having a shared color name.

I want to make it so the fruit is grouped by color name like so

```
Red
Red
Red
Green
Green
Red
Green

Becomes

Red
 Apple
 Strawberry 
 Cherry
 Cranberry

Green
  Grape
  Watermelon
  Pear

  $all_fruits->map(function ($item, $key) {

        });
```

All help much appreciated.

Comment: Hey last_shogun - what have _you tried?_ Please read up on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Essentially i am attempting to rolllup by like color namem i have tried map and mapWithKey with no success

Comment: please show us some code to start

Answer (score 0):

You might simply you the [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-groupby) function:

```
$allFruits->groupBy(function ($item) {
    // Or $item->color_name;
    return $item['color_name'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collected = $fruits->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
                return
                    [$item->fruitColor => $item->toArray()];
        });
```

Comment: addition of verbal explanations is often helpful in answers